# Issue seeing xticks with subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a problem to see x-axis description for first subplot (I used Axes.set_xticks). See sample of code:

```
import matplotlib.axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_lst=[100,200,150,500]
x_lst=[2,4,8,16]

plt.style.use("bmh") #"ggplot" "seaborn-v0_8-poster"
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex="all", squeeze=False, figsize=(15, 6))
ax_cur: matplotlib.axes.Axes = ax[0][0]

plt.suptitle("Performance",weight='bold', fontsize=18, ha="center", va="top")
ax_cur.set_title("title", fontsize=14,ha="center", va="top")

ax_cur.plot(x_lst, y_lst, color='green', linestyle="-")
ax_cur.legend()
ax_cur.set_ylabel('RTF [calls/sec]')
ax_cur.set_xticks(x_lst)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

See the output:
[image]

Did you solve the same problem?

Comment: @JohanC, works also, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate tick labels are turned off by default when you use *sharex*, but you can turn them back on with the `tick_params` method.

```
import matplotlib.axes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_lst=[100,200,150,500]
x_lst=[2,4,8,16]

plt.style.use("bmh") #"ggplot" "seaborn-v0_8-poster"
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex="all", squeeze=False, figsize=(15, 6))
ax_cur: matplotlib.axes.Axes = ax[0][0]

plt.suptitle("Performance",weight='bold', fontsize=18, ha="center", va="top")
ax_cur.set_title("title", fontsize=14,ha="center", va="top")

ax_cur.plot(x_lst, y_lst, color='green', linestyle="-")
ax_cur.legend()
ax_cur.set_ylabel('RTF [calls/sec]')
ax_cur.set_xticks(x_lst)
ax_cur.tick_params('x', labelbottom=True)

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use different x-axis description in subplots, you have to use different parameter setting for **sharex**, e.g.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex="none", squeeze=False, figsize=(15, 6))
```

see output:
[image]